# How to calculate DC power consumption of a device

Tags: radio, solar-cell, voltage-measurement

I've got an old car radio that I've mounted in my backyard, with some speakers. Right now it's running off an old battery I have, with a solar panel that trickle charges it during the day. I want to know, how many watts/volts it's using and what the solar panel is producing. The goal, would be to add another panel, so it can supplement the power more.. because I'm thinking about expanding it.

I've got a basic volt meter. If I have to buy something I will. I'm more cirious to learn about it then the

Comment: Devices do not "use" voltage.  You supply a voltage to a device and it uses *energy* by drawing current.  The total energy it's using will vary depending on the loudness of the music, and can be averaged out over time to produce an average number of watts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Watts = Volts x Amps

So, if you measure the amps flowing through the circuit, then multiply it by the voltage across the circuit, you will have the number of watts the system is using.

Switch your volt meter to a suitable voltage range and measure the voltage across the battery (should be somewhere around 12V).

Switch your volt meter to measure amps (if it can - if not get one that will) and connect it in between the battery and the stereo:

```
  ----(meter)--------
  |                 |
  +                 |
Battery           Stereo
  -                 |
  |                 |
  -------------------
```

Multiply the two readings, and voila!

Comment: measure the voltage while the load (the stereo) is attached.

Comment: and turned on and belting out some hardcore tunez

Comment: The measurement will fluctuate a lot with music.  You need to play something constant like a sine wave if you want an easily-readable current measurement.

Comment: if it's a radio that will *let* you tune to a blank spot on the dial, that would give you some nice even powered white noise.

Comment: when you switch your meter to current, just be sure that you put the meter in series with the circuit (i.e. you need to break the circuit and insert the ammeter), not in parallel...

Answer (score 2):

The previous answer was great for measuring the radio power.  This is one reason why it is handy to own two meters.  You can hook one up for current and then the other across the load for voltage.  Now you can get power without changing the setup.

Connect the meter in amps mode in line with the solar cell charging the battery to get an idea of the charging current in full sunlight.  At the battery voltage, this is also the power that the solar cell is providing.  You will have some charging losses, so all of this power will not be available for using the radio.

You should also include a diode in line with the solar cell.  It needs to be rated at the current of the maximum number of solar cells you expect to hook up in parallel.  The reason for this diode is that a solar cell is a poor diode.  I will discharge the battery during dark times when it is not producing any voltage.  The diode prevents this at a cost of power during the charging (0.6V * Charging Current).

If you are manually attaching the solar panel on in the daylight, this diode is not needed.